# Intuition behind the Galois Group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I've just learned the definition of the Galois Group. Although I understand the formal definition, I'm having a hard time understanding the intuition behind it. So my question is: **intuitively, what information about a field extension does the Galois Group capture?** I'm looking for an answer along the lines of: "it measures the symmetries of the field extension", but hopefully something a little more concrete.

To be clear, I understand how the Galois Group is *used* in practice (e.g: it allows you to convert problems about fields into problems about groups, which are normally a lot easier to tackle). But I'm asking, aside from its practical utility, why is the Galois Group important? What information does the Galois Group give us about the "symmetries" of a field extension? (And what does "symmetry" even mean in this context?) Any clarification would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thinking about the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ with two elements:

- the identity automorphism
- the complex conjugation automorphism

So the Galois group detects a mapping within elements of group that does not affect the basic group structure.

Notice that if a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ has a complex zero it instantly has its conjugate as another zero, but essentially we cannot really say which one is which. We do mark them as $a+bi$ and $a-bi$, but the agreement about $i$ is implicit, we could easily replace $i$ with $j=-i$ and $-j$ and start calling $j$ imaginary unit and nothing would change among polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$.

In that sense, a Galois field is talking about how much the elements within a group are indistinguishable among each other.

A Galois group contains mapping that are preserving the structure. The same idea you have all around math. Even and odd numbers, for example, you do not have to take care about the exact parity for the basic mathematical operations in order to get the parity of the entire expression, and so on. The basic idea, here, is not more complex than that.

It is somewhat unfortunate that modern math places Galois where it really does not belong, in some sort of advanced math. It is there if you take into account a general math overview, but so is multiplication and addition. It is still a simple thing.

Comment: That's a wonderful explanation. That explains it really nicely: any polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ that has $i$ as a complex root also has $-i$ as a root. So if you swap $i$ and $-i$, there is no polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ that would "feel" the difference. So $\text{Gal } \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ measures to what extent polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ "notice" it when you swap their roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But that leads to the question: why is that something that we would want to measure? That is, why would we want to know when polynomials with coefficients in the base field can detect it when you swap roots in the top field? What insight would that give us?

Comment: This structure of Galois group has its own structure and then this substructure has its own. Notice that once you have this Galois group recognized for example as a symmetric group then you can apply the knowledge about that group and reason about how the structure of symmetric group reflects something within polynomial.
This is how we got to the explanation over which polynomial has a solution expressible in radicals. It is all about the structure hidden within Galois group. It is interesting to know what property of polynomial is reflected within its Galois group and the other way around.